# How to configure terserplugin to not mangle classnames

Tags: angular, webpack, terser

Classnames are mangled during minification, but that should not be done

I tried setting the reserved property when mangling as described here https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin#terseroptions. Unfortunately that doesn't work for me.

I have a repo on bitbucket that contains the problem, https://bitbucket.org/JohanBeumer/angular-ivy-aot/src/master/.

**I noticed I made a mistake by not commiting the latest sources to bitbucket. Sorry for that, I updated the repo.**

De custom webpack config I use in that repo is as follows :

```
module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                terserOptions: {
                    // https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin#terseroptions
                    compress: false,
                    keep_fnames: true,
                    keep_classnames: true,
                    mangle: {
                        keep_fnames: true,
                        keep_classnames: true,
                        properties: {
                            reserved: ['Foo', 'BaseModel']
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
    }
};
```

I expect the title of the screen to show the name of the class, which is 'Foo'.

I build the app using the command : `ng build --prod --aot`

The actual question I have is, how can I prevent webpack minify from mangling the classname?

Thanks for the response Tony Ngo. I added keep_fnames as you suggested but unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem. Now I get the the following error in the console :

[image: Console error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to finish up this question. I ended up creating an issue with Webpack at first and later on with Angular-cli.

[Webpack issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9258)

[Angular-cli issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14779)

The takeaway is, you can configure terserPlugin, but Angular ignores that configuration when it comes to mangling.

To save yourself time, instead of dynamically trying to get the classname add a property with that same name and use that.